# Method and field in parent or base class

Tags: c#, oop

I have an `Employee` base class and a `FullTimeEmp` and a `PartTimeEmp` derived classes. I want to be able to get the type of an employee using a method. I am planning to set the `EmployeeType` in the constructor in the `FullTimeEmp` and `PartTimeEmp` class.

Should I put the `GetEmployeeType` method and the field `employeeType` in the base class or in the derived class? All Employees must have an employeeType and be able to return the employeeType but the value are set in the derived classes.

Edit: I know how to code both alternatives but I don't know which is the correct alternative from an oop perspective. I did not think this was a matter of opinion. I thought there was one correct and one incorrect way of coding.

Comment: What is the EmployeeType function supposed to return? A string? An enum? Can you give example of value?

Comment: Unless they have different logic, why not just have a `bool` property called something like `EmployedFullTime`? This can then either be true (employed full time) or false (employed part time).

Comment: Bools are generally a poor choice for this, unless you're absolutely sure you're never going to have more than 2 values. If he decides to add a Contractor type, he'll have to do a lot of easily avoidable refactoring. I'd stick to enums or strings.

Comment: @Evgeni What if the Contractor is part time?

Comment: Don't know. Ask BA. Maybe you'll need another type, maybe you'll have a PTContractor type.

Comment: I can see that I'm not very clear in my question. I know how to write the code for the method and field but I don't know where it's best (from OOP perspective) to put it, in the base class or derived class given the conditions stated? (sorry for my confusing english :-))

Comment: Place the enumeration of Employee types in the base class. Place an abstract method `GetEmployeeType` in the base class. Make each derived class override `GetEmployeeType`, and return one of the enumerated values. You probably do not need a `m_employeeType`. What's the point of stashing it away as a data member?

Comment: So you are saying that it's better to implement the method in all derived classes returning e.g. an enum rather than setting a field in the base class (e.g. using the constructor in the derived class) and implementing the get method in the base class. This despite that the get methods in the derived classes probably will look exactly the same? I hope this make sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want this is a possible solution:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Type EmployeeType { get { return GetType(); } }
}

public class FullTimeEmp : Employee { }
```

You don't need to set the `Type` in derived class in this case. If you want to return something else as a string, this is another solution:

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual string EmployeeType { get { return "Employee"; } }
}

public class FullTimeEmp : Employee { 
    public override string EmployeeType { get { return "FullTimeEmp"; } }
}
```

And with an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    public abstract string EmployeeType { get; }
}

public class FullTimeEmp : Employee { 
    public override string EmployeeType { get { return "FullTimeEmp"; } }
}
```

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    public abstract string Type { get; }
}

public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public override string Type { get; } = "Full Time";
}
```

Comment: I'd never name that property as `Type` ...

Comment: This is a sample code I put together in 30 seconds.. You're free to name it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

To see the type of the `Employee`, you can use the `Object.GetType()` function in your instance, it will returns a `Type` object.
Example

```
FullTimeEmp emp = new FullTimeEmp();
Type t = emp.GetType();
```

You can check more info about it on [Object.GetType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT:

As both parent classes need the employeeType you can set the field employeeType and method GetEmployeeType on the base class, and set the value of the field on the parent classes constructor.

Or like Evgeni said, you can also make the base class abstract, put a abstract get property, and each parent class implement their own version of that property.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.